# Permission denied writing file from Android Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to write a file in my android cordova plugin. This actually works fine my side, but when my client slots the plugin into the rest of the app then it can no longer write the file. The error is "java.io.IOException: Permission denied" at the point of writing the file.

I have specified the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in my manifest and also written the code to request permissions at run time. They pop up and I click accept. But for some reason it still cannot write the file out, and has permission denied error mentioned above.

Does anyone know what I can do? I cannot work out at all why this happens, and is especially weird that a) it works fine for me, and b) it USED to work fine for the client too until maybe 2 weeks ago.

Code for making file (pretty standard, and works fine for me and saves to /storage/emulated/0/proto/2018_01_12_17_15_26_Image.jpg, only stops working when client integrates into main cordova app )

```
// Create the file directory
File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , "proto");
myDir.mkdirs();

debug("does the dir exist @ "+myDir.getAbsolutePath());
debug("myDir exists? "+myDir.exists());
if (!myDir.exists())
{
  Tools.toast("failed to create dir "+myDir.getAbsolutePath(),c);
}

// create the file in the directory
File file = new File(myDir, fname);
try {
  debug("creating file."+file.getAbsolutePath());
  boolean fileCreated = file.createNewFile();
  debug("fileCreated?"+fileCreated);
  if (fileCreated) {
    debug("write bitmap to "+file.getAbsolutePath());
    // write the bitmap to that file
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    //maybe faster to use jpeg?

    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, outputStream);
    //bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
    debug("FILE WAS CREATED");

    //put in gallery on phone
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "My title" , "My Description");
  }
  else
  {
    Tools.toast("Failed! File was not created.",c);
  }
} catch (IOException ex) {
  debug("SAVE FAILED could not save file!!! "+ex.getMessage());
  //Tools.toast("Could not save file: "+ex.getMessage(),c);
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Well tell full file path to begin wth.

Comment: Share your code snippet here

Comment: added code, though I don't think its the problem, I think it is some Cordova weirdness.

Comment: Are you sure your client hasn't removed the permission?

Comment: Good question, but they sent me the full project integrated into cordova as a android studio project, permissions look fine and it will not save for me using their project either. Permission denied even though they're all granted :(